# SCIPY create bounds for multiple variables using a loop

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, bounds

I did not find this specific question asked here. I am using scipy to optimize a linear program that has multiple variables...not just 3 or 4 (shown in most examples/documentation). In the examples I have seen, the number of variables is small, so the bounds for each variable can be literally listed. 
However, I have a matrix of variables - specifically the upper triangular of a 12* 12 that I need to specify bounds for. I've not been able to come up with a way of doing this.

```
import numpy as np

#matrix of values that will be "changed" by solver to optimize:
x = np.triu(np.ones((12, 12)),1)

#bounds:
bnds = (0,100)
```

1. I need to create the same bounds for all the elements of x.
2. I need to make sure that the way the bounds are created is accepted by the scipy optimize routine.

I tried the following:

```
mxbnds = np.ones((12,12),dtype=object)
for i in range(0,len(schedule0)):
    for j in range(0,len(schedule0)):
        mxbnds[i,j] = bnds
```

But when I attempt to optimize using:

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
sol = opt.minimize(val, schedule0, method='SLSQP', bounds= mxbnds)
```

I get the error

> "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence"

I think this is linked to the way I'm creating bounds, it doesn't seem correct. Any help would be appreciated. 
I can provide a smaller reproducible version of the problem, including the objective function if needed. I am hoping someone has done this before and could point out what I'm doing wrong just by looking at the way I'm creating the bounds.
Thanks!

More attempts:
I just tried:

```
bnds = [[bnds for j in x] for i in x]
```

This creates the bnds, but now I get another error:

```
IndexError: SLSQP Error: the length of bounds is not compatible with that of x0.
```

Does seem like a little progress it seems......

Comment: The `optimization vector x` used in *scipy.minimize* must be *1-d*. So you can't use a matrix. You need to use a *flattened matrix* and *reshape* it within your defined functions later. If your `x` is *1d*, bounds is easily build by a list-comprehension.

Comment: Thanks @sascha. I followed your suggestion, that works, but now I get the "iteration limit exceeded" error. I wonder if I need to use another solver for this problem. Would appreciate any suggestions. thanks!

Comment: @sascha - would you recommend any solver library that uses 2D matrices/arrays instead of scipy? Just the nature of the problem I'm solving....I def need to have something that uses matrices. I was thinking of exploring "GEKKO" unless you have any suggestions. thanks again!

Comment: All (or most) solvers are based on a variable-vector in it's core. The matrix or not decision is just syntactic sugar. There is no real optimization-problem presented here, so there is nothing to recommend. It's clear, that there are some powerful  solvers available outside of scipy, but none of those is as easily used as those within scipy.

Comment: @sascha - understood.I'll make a new thread with a reproducible version of the problem, and would really appreciate some advice.